# Is there a relatively easy way to monitor data I/O per program in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, monitoring

Relevant system info:

- Windows 10 Professional
- Samsung QVO 860 2 TB
- 6 HDDs

I have recently calculated that my system is writing approximately 1.9 GB per hour to my new SSD and I wish to log which programs are the most consuming. 
I do not wish to simply see the realtime data speeds reported by Task Manager,
as most programs are not constantly running. 
I wish to see a report; for example, a weekly chart.

I run several servers, occasionally from the main drive and wish to see specific programs that write high amounts over time. I see programs such as "Storage Reports Management" available for Windows Server, not Pro. Are there any reasonable alternatives?

I'm not interested in specific data or recovery, simply throughput logs.

Comment: I need this too to protect SSD. Maybe this can be only achieved with 3rd party software, post the question here too https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Change your title to "How to monitor data I/O per program in Windows?" because the answer is hard.

Comment: Well, I do not have an answer still, however I found the source of the data write. A daily server backup was writing 28.8GB a day, driving that average up exponentially.